# What event logs exist in Windows and what is their purpose?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, event-log

I only know one event log named "Other". I want to know the name of all event logs, which exist in Windows. Additionally I want to know what purpose these event logs (including "Other") have.

I am referring to event logs in Windows XP.

Comment: This question is very broad and somewhat unclear.  Could you please add some more information or possibly more direction as to what you are looking for?

Comment: You also need to say which version of Windows since things have changed somewhat in more recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

#### I want to know the name of all event logs

That's not possible as anybody can [create their own event log](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/02/01/use-powershell-to-create-and-to-use-a-new-event-log/).

In addition:

> In older versions of Windows everything got dumped into the Application or System log, in the more modern editions **there are dozens or hundreds of different logs to choose from**. Each Windows component will most likely have its own log.

Source [Using Event Viewer to Troubleshoot Problems](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson3/)

The following screen shot (from Windows 7) shows just how many event logs there are:

[image]

Note:

- I don't have a event log named "Other"

There are, however, some standard event logs.

These include:

> - **Application Log** Records events logged by applications, such as the failure of MS SQL to access a database.
> - **Directory Service** Records events logged by Active Directory and its related services.
> - **DNS Server** Records DNS queries, responses, and other DNS activities.
> - **File Replication Service** Records file replication activities on the system.
> - **Security Log** Records events you've set for auditing with local or global group policies.
> - **System Log** Records events logged by the operating system or its components, such as the failure of a service to start at bootup.

Source [Event Logging and Viewing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726966.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)